# 'unsupported initialize for address space' error from kernel code

Tags: opencl

I know this question got asked before, but for me it works on one simple kernel, and not on the other one, which is more complicated. More details :

> :0:0: in function shift_and_roll_without_sum_loop void (float
>   addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*, float
>   addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*, float
>   addrspace(1)*, i32 addrspace(1)*, i32 addrspace(1)*, float
>   addrspace(1)*, float addrspace(1)*): unsupported initializer for
>   address space

My `clinfo` :

https://pastebin.com/vyaz6f1h

In the methode kernel i made a call like this :

```
computeCorrespondencesCL(transform,model_voxelized,point_cloud_ptr, correspondence_result, model_voxelized_size, point_cloud_ptr_size,input_transformed);
```

Whereas the methode called is a methode inside kernel :

```
void computeCorrespondencesCL(__private float *guess4f,__global float *input, __global float *target,__global float *correspondence_result,__global int *size_input, __global int *size_output, __global float *input_transformed ) {
```

Shift and roll methode :

```
__kernel void shift_and_roll_without_sum_loop(__global float* floatArgs, __global float* count, __global float* initialTranslation, __global float* direction,__global float* model_voxelized, __global float* point_cloud_ptr, __global float *rotation, __global int *model_voxelized_size, __global int *point_cloud_ptr_size, __global float *correspondence_result, __global float *input_transformed) {
```

Is there anything wrong with the way this method is called.?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to initialise a variable in a way that's not compatible with its storage address space, but I'm guessing you know that and still can't find the problem, so you're going to have to post the code for your `shift_and_roll_without_sum_loop` function, or at least all the variable declarations in it.

Comment: @pmdj please see update. I might found the problem.

Comment: The problem probably lies with the types, and you haven't posted those. You'll need to show us the declarations & initialisations of the variables you're passing to the function. So what are the types for `transform,model_voxelized,point_cloud_ptr, correspondence_result, model_voxelized_size, point_cloud_ptr_size,input_transformed`?

Comment: @pmdj please see my update, thank you :D